# The difference between modify and modify_key in boost multi_index_container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

What is the difference between `modify` and `modify_key` in boost multi_index_container. I read their documentation both and I can't seem to find the difference between the usages of both.

[Link to the documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`modify_key` is a variation of `modify` that saves you some typing when the only part of the element you want to change is the key itself. For instance, if I define a `multi_index_container` such as:

```
struct element
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

using namespace boost::multi_index;

using container=multi_index_container<
  element,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<member<element,int,&element::x>>
  >
>;

container c=...;
```

Then the following:

```
auto it=...;
c.modify(it,[](element& e){e.x=3;});
```

can be written with `modify_key` as

```
auto it=...;
c.modify_key(it,[](int& x){x=3;});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already figured this out as I stated in my answer. Accepted for the detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the difference between the usages of both (as far as I understood is as follows):

- Modify:

  The functor is passed a reference to the whole object that was retrieved  and the functor can modify any of the members of this retrieved object.
- Modify_Key:

  The functor modifies only the key that is used in searching for and retrieving the object. For instance, using an index with the *name* member of a class to search the container, upon applying modify_key on the returned iterator, the name member will be changed.

Basically modify_key is a special case from modify.